# How to use rank in sql but order by where filed equals to a constant

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here how my data set is. I have `customerid` and program names.
A customer can have multiple program names. I want to rank the data and PARTITION BY customerId and ORDER BY program name. But I want to give rank one to a particular program 'abc'. Then I can select the rank one only and remove duplicates.

Is there a way to rank and order based on where program equal to 'abc'?

Comment: this looks like an interesting question - but - what have you tried so far? Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If, at least, you can add example of your input data and desired result - this will make it at a min!

Comment: Sure let me update that

Comment: i went ahead based on how i understood your question  - see the answer

Answer (score 1):

> I want to rank the data and partition by customer I'd and order by program name. But I want to give rank one to a particular program 'abc'.

Assuming program name cannot be NULL - below should do the trick

```sql
SELECT customerid, program, 
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY IF(program = 'abc', NULL, program)) AS rnk
FROM yourTable
```

You can test/play with dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT pair.customerid, pair.program
  FROM UNNEST([STRUCT<customerid INT64, program STRING>
    (1,'aaa'), (1, 'p2'), (1, 'abc'), (1, 'p3'), 
    (2,'x7'), (2, 'aba'), (2, 'abc'), (2, 'x4')
  ]) AS pair
)
SELECT customerid, program, 
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY IF(program = 'abc', NULL, program)) AS rnk
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY customerid, rnk
```

result will be

```sql
customerid  program rnk  
1           abc     1    
1           aaa     2    
1           p2      3    
1           p3      4    
2           abc     1    
2           aba     2    
2           x4      3    
2           x7      4
```